# Angular2/rxjs: Subscribe not firing on Observable expression of mergeMaps & forkJoins

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service that has a method that is essentially:

```
this.backend.getJSON(`${name}/book`).mergeMap(
  book => Observable.forkJoin(book.parts.map((partName: string) =>
    this.backend.getJSON(`${name}/${partName}/part`).mergeMap(
      part => Observable.forkJoin(part.sections.map((sectionName: string) =>
        this.backend.getJSON(`${name}/${partName}/${sectionName}/section`).mergeMap(
          section => Observable.forkJoin(section.chapters.map((chapterName: string) =>
            this.backend.getJSON(`${name}/${partName}/${sectionName}/${chapterName}/chapter`).map(chapter => {
              this.transform(chapter.content, `${name}/${partName}/${sectionName}/${chapterName}`);
              return chapter;
            }))),
          this.assignAndReturn('chapters'))),
      this.assignAndReturn('sections'))))),
  this.assignAndReturn('parts'));
```

(I've inlined - and slightly simplified - some called methods, which is why it's such a huge expression, and hence the repetition in the `getJSON` args.)

`assignAndReturn` is just:

```
private assignAndReturn<T1, T2>(name: string) {
  return (a: T1, b: T2) => {
    a[name] = b;
    return a;
  };
}
```

`.subscribe(...)`ing to this doesn't seem to work. It seems to only get partway down the expression tree, not 'making it' all the way to getting the chapters.

I really don't know what's happening. It's almost as if I need to be subscribing to the 'inner' parts, but then the outer subscription won't fire...

Answer (score 0):

You could try a pattern like this, leveraging `flatMap`. Once the previous event finishes, `flatMap` will continue with the `Observable` returned by it's callback. It helps with readability quite a bit and enables you to spy on your stream along the way.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

class Demo {
    backend = {
        // Simulated request
        getJSON: (str, demoValue) => Observable.of(demoValue).delay(new Date(Date.now() + 1000))
    }

    getBook(name) {
        this.backend
            // Get the book
            .getJSON(`${name}/book`, name)
            // Get the parts
            .flatMap(book => { 
                // Observable.from() will create an observable event
                // for each item in the array
                return this.backend
                    .getJSON(`[Next URL]`, [`${book}/part1`, `${book}/part2`])
                    .flatMap(parts => Observable.from(parts));
            })
            // Get the sections
            .flatMap(part => {
                return this.backend
                    .getJSON(`[Next URL]`, [`${part}/section1`, `${part}/section`])
                    .flatMap(sections => Observable.from(sections));
            })
            // Get the chapters
            .flatMap(section => {
                return this.backend
                    .getJSON(`[Next URL]`, [`${section}/chapter1`, `${section}/chapter2`])
                    .flatMap(chapters => Observable.from(chapters));
            })
            // etc.
            .subscribe(console.log)
    }
}

let t = new Demo();
t.getBook('cool');
```

This outputs:

```
cool/part1/section1/chapter1
cool/part1/section1/chapter2
cool/part1/section2/chapter1
cool/part1/section2/chapter2
cool/part2/section1/chapter1
cool/part2/section1/chapter2
cool/part2/section2/chapter1
cool/part2/section2/chapter2
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I'd really like the book itself to be emitted from the observable (rather than the chapters, which I want to be part of the book structure). All I want the method returning the observable to be returning is the book, it's just that it needs to recursively 'resolve' some fields before doing so.

Comment: Particularly, I don't want the book to emit from the observable before it's fully formed. I'm subscribing to `getBook(name)` from a resolver, and I don't want the page loading until the data's loaded

Comment: You can take the above structure and add `.toArray()` to the end. This will gather all of the results into an array before moving forward. After witch you could use `.map( ... )` to recombine it however you need.

Comment: I ended up converting the code to being in terms of `Promise`s and using `then`/`all`, but I'd still like to know what's wrong with my posted code and why it doesn't work... I'll leave the question open in case anyone knows